# Struggle with HeightRequest in .NET MAUI App

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I use a Frame which should not have a visible Border at the Bottom. To reach that, I used a little trick and just set the HeightRequest to a value that is high enough so that the Border at the bottom is not visible anymore.

Additionally, I use a Sharpnado CollectionView to display elements which uses the same trick with a HeightRequest value high enough so that the content can be scrolled and visibly moved by a user.

To me, setting a HeightRequest in such a way or setting a HeightRequest/WidthRequest in general is a bit too tricky and the same as setting an absolute value, which is not really good when thinking of different display sizes and resolutions on different devices.

Is there a way to set the Height in relation to a possible display size or something like that so that I can say, okay use "DisplayHeight + 50" or "DisplayHeight - 100" or something like that?

Do you have better ideas or recommendations to prevent setting such absolute values and work in a good way on different resolutions?

Comment: XAML: `<Frame x:Name="myFrame" ...>`, in code-behind constructor: after InitializeComponent but before setting BIndingContext: `myFrame.HeightRequest = ...;` Then you can use whatever formula you want.

Comment: That's a good hint to do it there. Do you have any recommendations on how to do the calculations correctly for different target Displays as there are other elements on top of my Frame. Currently, when I work in my corresponding emulator, I know what HeightRequest I need so that it looks good, but how would I to that for other target systems? I could detect `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height` and also work with that, but I think there is a need to know what the start (Y-value) of the Frame is or something like that, when you know what I mean? There is a gut feeling I have to recalc everythin

Comment: *"there are other elements on top of my Frame"* - try to simplify the situation. Maybe set HeightRequest of several elements based on screen height. So that everything adjusts together?